# How can I use data from sql table in a graph using matplotlib?

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I am making a project in which I need to make a bar chart of a table (of subjects and marks) from MySql.

When I try to iterate through the values obtained using-

```
 cursor.execute(select...)
```

an error occurs...
None type not iterable

Are there any other methods to do this?
Here is my code-

```
connection=mysql.connector.connect(...)
cursor=connection.cursor()

sql="SELECT COUNT(subjects) FROM table WHERE marks=20"

count=[]

for j in cursor.execute(sql):
      count.append(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having a trouble with what is that SQL query returning (that apparently is a None value).

Also even if the query return would be working right, it is returning a number (count of subjects) which is neither iterable.

Comment: So can i directly assign count=cursor.execute(sql)

Comment: I think the query itself is returning a null value

Comment: Yes its returning nothing thus the error. You could straight assign  count=cursor.execute(sql) but first check why that query is returning None (maybe the query itself is returning nothing, I would try it on an externar DB client)